# How can I extract hashtags from strings and export as a csv?

Tags: r, string, export, export-to-csv, hashtag

I use the following function to extract hashtags from text data:

```
a <- c("#aaa", "#bbb", "#ccc")
hashtag_pat <- "#[a-zA-Z0-9_-ー\\.]+"
hashtag <- str_extract_all(a, hashtag_pat)
```

Here's the output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "#aaa"

[[2]]
[1] "#bbb"

[[3]]
[1] "#ccc"
```

I can't, however, export this correctly as a csv. I need all these words in a single cell (separated by spaces). What is the best way to export this?
The following is what 'write.csv' gives me. I appreciate if you could help fix this. [image]

Comment: Use `paste(hashtag, collapse = " ")` before writing the output?

Comment: What is your expected output in the csv file with or without hashtag?

Comment: I needed the # sign too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update after clarification:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = paste(a,collapse=" "))
df
```

```
            col1
1 #aaa #bbb #ccc
```

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
hashtag <- sub("^\\#", "", a)
write.csv(data.frame(t(unlist(hashtag))), "my_file.csv")
```

[image]

Comment: I actually wanted all the hashtags in one cell, separate by spaces.

Comment: Please see my update. I hope that I understand you correctly!

Comment: Thank you very much. This solves the problem. Highly appreciate it!